# format cell in flexigrid to show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexigrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Does anybody know how I can format cell in flexigrid to show value in currency for example euro with separator "," and for cents "."

I import value with JSON but don't know how to change look of that number to be like amount to pay.

Thx...

Comment: The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Looks like it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer formatting your currencies from **Server-Side** before sending your data to the client.

In case your building your data using XML, format your data as following:

```
<cell>Salary.ToString("#,#")</cell>
```

This example is for .Net use, but in case your using other languages I think you got my idea.

puppybeard put a link for your question, but this approach leads for ugly code (in my opinion).

Comment: yes i founded solution in server side... Its better to use BigDecimal and Utils command to format as currency...